# Array to Dictionary (without Loop)

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, type-conversion

Suppose, I have array like this:

```
var array = ["zero","one","two", "three"]
```

I want to convert it to `Dictionary`, but key as an index of array element and value is element it self like:

```
var dic = [0:"zero", 1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"]
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894798-init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might use a combo of `Dictionary.uniqueKeysWithValues` and `zip`:

```
var array = ["zero","one","two", "three"]
var dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(array.indices, array))
print(dict) // [0:"zero", 1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three"]
```

Comment: Or `0..<array.count`.

Comment: Or `zip(array.indices, array)`